# Images with tags database design considerations

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I am designing a database that contains photos.

A photo can have none or more tags associated with it.

Currently I have all tagwords/keywords in a column separated by spaces per image record.

Now I know this is not good design, because it's possible to have an image record that has an empty tagwords/keywords column, and it will also make things inefficient to bring back all photos that contain the word e.g. 'Horse' in.

So my question is, would it be better to have keywords in their own table and a record per keyword?

The table could have columns ID(INT PK), imageId(INT KEY), keyword(VARCHAR).

The only issue I see with this is that I could end up with hundreds of repeated keywords for each image?

Someone mentioned briefly at work something about lookup tables to solve this issue but they didn't explain what it was exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another table including say named tags with fields id, keyword. And in the table instead of keyword use id of the tags table.

Comment: Thanks, it makes perfect sense. I created a reference table to connect the images to keywords, since the ref table is just a load of numbers I don't see any major performance problems especially with the small number of images I have.

Comment: @imperium2335 By the way this is called table normalization. You wrote "Currently I have all tagwords/keywords in a column separated by spaces per image record." Sometimes this can also be a way of db design. But in general you should avoid it. It's non-atomic form. One field should not contain multiple values.

Answer (score -1):

Space-separated or otherwise delimited is probably your worst option.  You don't need a lookup table for all your tags though, I would do something like:

```
T_PHOTO
photo_id = 1, photo_name = hello

T_PHOTO_TAG
photo_id = 1, tag = pretty
photo_id = 1, tag = sunset
photo_id = 1, tag = kitten
```

etc

Crucially you do not need a T_TAG with all these words.  That said, you **could** - if you wanted a finite tag universe, that is.

Answer (score -1):

"The table could have columns ID(INT PK), imageId(INT KEY), keyword(VARCHAR)." That isn't normalized either, because if you want to add a keyword to multiple photos it would appear multiple times in such a table.

What you need is an m:n relation, making use of a third table:

```
PHOTOS – at least an ID
KEYWORDS – ID and KEYWORD
PHOTO_HAS_KEYWORD – PHOTO.ID and KEYWORD.ID as combined PRIMARY or UNIQUE key with according foreign keys on them.
```

You should read some introduction to database normalization to get an understanding of how an m:n relation works in such a case.

Answer (score -1):

My preference would be to store keywords / tags only once and reuse them for other images.

An Image has and belongs to many tags

**Image**

- id
- name
- file
- etc

**Tags**

- id
- name
- created

**images_tags**

- image_id
- tag_id

You could then use a group concatenation on all the tags for a given image record. 
see - [Aggregate functions and grouping](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)